# How to change Y-Axis dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have an array of data being interpreted by dc.js into bar graphs, however every time that I create a new graph, it always has the number of instances in a group on the y-axis. I would like to know if I can change this, and run a function on each element in the group before outputting it to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear what you are asking for, but it sounds like you may be looking for either the crossfilter [custom reduce function](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduce), or the one of the [tricks for pre-filtering data](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted).

If not, please edit your question and add more details.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it. As the other answer said, the custom reduce function is required to create the variables to be projected on the y-axis, but the real attribute that accesses the y-axis is the ".valueAccessor" attribute of dc charts.